# Logical error: Max always "0"?

Tags: java

I try to write a program to finding Max number but the result appear "0". This is my code:

```
public class Max_N_value {
    public Max_N_value() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i; int mynum[] = new int[50];

        for( i=0;i<5;i++) 

            mynum[i]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Value "));

        if(mynum[i]>mynum[i+1]) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Maximum value is "+mynum[i]);
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Maximum value is  : "+mynum[i+1]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Hitnt: What's the value of `i` by the time you reach the `if` statement?

Comment: The code above is missing parts.  Please include them, and indent for the benefit of readers.

Comment: if you would have formatted your code propperly and used more brackstes, you would see that the brackets enclosing for are missing

Comment: and i is only use in the for-loop so write this: `for(int i=0;i<5;i++)`

Comment: Your code isn't doing what you think. It always returns the number input.

Comment: There is still code missing.  The open brace of the if is not closed.

Comment: Thank for comment.
Can you please correct it step by step?  

I'm a new learner of JAVA.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your code asks the user to input five numbers, and assigns them to the first five slots in an array. Then it compares the six and seventh slots, both zero, and always executes the second print statement, since the two numbers are always the same.

The right way to do this is to start with a variable initialized to a value smaller than any possible entered value (Integer.MIN_VALUE works) and then loop over the whole array, comparing each value to that variable. If the value in the array is larger than the variable, set the variable to the value in the array. At the end of this process, the variable will hold the largest value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work.  If the purpose is only to calculate the maximum of 5 numbers, there is absolutely no need to read them in an array.

```
public class Max_N_value {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int max= Integer.MIN_VALUE ;
       for(int i= 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
          int newNum= Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Value ") ) ;
          if( newNum > max ) max= newNum ;
       }
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Maximum value is "+ max );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   int[] mynum = new int[5];
   int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   for (int i = 0; i < mynum.length; i++) {
      mynum[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
          "" + (i+1) + ". Value "));
      ...
   }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Maximum value is  : "+max);
```

This uses `int[] mynum` instead of the old notation which is less logical: `int mynum[]`.

There should be one loop for inputting, the `i` restricted to the loop.
There you could determine a maximum (...). Sometimes it is better having a variable for the result too.

Comment: Some explanation as to _why_ would be useful for OP.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill very right, did not look like a programmer; disarmed a bit

Answer (score -2):

**Edited**

Now code is corrected.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int i; 
       int mynum[] = new int[5];
       int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

       for( i=0; i< mynum.length; i++)
       {
          int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Value"));
          if(num > max) max = num;
       }
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Maximum number is: "+max);
   }
```

Comment: This code is too inefficient.  The second `for` could start at 1.  This is tongue-in-cheek, of course.

Comment: In fact, this code doesn't work.  The condition for the second `for` should be i < 4.

Comment: @Mario No need to start for at i=1